# create buckets in array by reading length of that array

Tags: javascript

I am developing an application where n  no of records in a single array will be created. So when  array's length  reached to (every bucket) 300 should create a bucket like this

```
        let arr = [0:{},....300:{},[0:{}.....300:[]...]]
```

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cut your array to chunks like that:

```js
function arrayToChunks(array, chunkSize) {
    const result = [];
    const arraySize = array.length;

    for (let i = 0; i < arraySize; i += chunkSize) {
        result.push(array.slice(i, i + chunkSize));
    }

    return result;
}
```

Usage:

```js
const fullArray = [/* some large array */];
const chunkedArray = arrayToChunks(arr, 300);
```